# How to get the table name from the Exception(Reference) in .Net using MS SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My code -

```
try
    {
        currentPane.ViewController.Delete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
/* -- Need to find the Expression for getting the Table Name -- */


            string title = "DeleteButton_Click Error " + contentPane.TabHeader;
            if(ex.InnerException != null)
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            else
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

            var service = new InsurableRisk.Service.ApplicationExceptionService();
            try
            {
                service.Save(ex);
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                service.Dispose();
                service = null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

While capture an refrencial integrity exception in my MVVM application, i see the table name in the ex.InnerException.Message

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Policy_InsuranceCarrier". The conflict occurred in database "InsurableRisk", *table "dbo.Policy"*, column 'InsuranceCarrierKey'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

But i am not able to figure the Expression which will pull the table name.
Any pointers  ?

Comment: What's the type of the InnerException (i.e. what does `ex.InnerException.GetType().FullName` return)?

Comment: @MichaelGunter it returns "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

Comment: Looks like you'll need to manually extract it from the string. SqlException (and it's child SqlError object) do not expose the table name that caused the error.

Comment: It's a mistake to depend on the format of an Exception message. It's meant to be human-readable text, not machine-readable text.